# setting up a rails saas archictecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saas

When setting up a saas environment for rails, you often see that the shared code, for example an authentication system is an engine and included in all the client apps.

I was thinking of doing it the other way around, so make a main app with shared code and include the client apps as engines. I was thinking that this approach has some advantages: there is actualy only one app to deploy which i think is easier and there will be less ruby instances. It is also easy to put extra stuff in the master app

Wat do you think, is this a good approach or are there disadvantages i didn't think of?